# Do you play with other people in training modes?

Tags: overwatch

I assume you do, as it is possible to get kicked in training modes "Practice Range" and "Practice vs. AI" (doesn't appear to be possible in Tutorial):

> You were removed from the match due to inactivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't play with other people in the Practice Range.
You do play with other people, but not against other people, in Practice vs AI.